# OPTIONAL triple in DELETE WHERE query

Tags: sparql

I have a resource `http://example.com/entity/something` of `rdf:type` `ex:sometype` that I want to delete. The resource **might or might not** have `?something`. In case, it `ex:has` `?something`, I also want to delete the relationship (but, of course, not the resource `?something`).

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX ex: <http://example.com/#>
DELETE WHERE {
       <http://example.com/entity/something> rdf:type ex:sometype ;
                 ex:has ?something .
```

This works but only if `<http://example.com/entity/something> ex:has ?something`. I tried to make the second statament optional with `OPTIONAL{}` but it doesn't seem to work with `DELETE WHERE`.

Comment: *"doesn't seem to work"* is not a helpful statement...What does not work?
 Error, unexpected result?

Comment: In addtion, be careful: something like *"I also want to delete the relationship (but, of course, not the resource ?something)."* is some kind of misleading as an RDF dataset is a set of triples `(s p o)`, thus, you can only remove triples. If there are other triple `(o p1 o2)`, then `o` would still "exist" in the dataset

Comment: Actually, I guess you can only use simple triples (see [the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rQuadPattern) )in the short form  `DELETE WHERE`, thus, you should try `PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX ex: <http://example.com/#>
DELETE {<http://example.com/entity/something> rdf:type ex:sometype ;
                 ex:has ?something . } WHERE {
       <http://example.com/entity/something> rdf:type ex:sometype ;
                OPTIONAL{<http://example.com/entity/something> ex:has ?something .}}`

Answer (score 2):

Multiple operations can be given in a single request, separated by ";"

`DELETE WHERE { <http://example.com/entity/something> rdf:type ex:sometype }
;
DELETE WHERE { <http://example.com/entity/something> ex:has ?something  }`

The first deletes all the type statements, the second any `ex:has` statements.

By separating them, deleting the type statements does not depend on matching the `ex:has`.

The full DELETE form using OPTIONAL given by @AKSW will also work.